# Which of the following approaches (framework features x application context) fits best to a react-native / redux application?

Tags: architecture, react-native, directory, redux, project-organization

Considering a react-native application with redux which of the following directory / files organization is more recommended? Or in a better way: which is more adequate to a react-native / redux application?

Let suppose this application simulates a store (sell products...)

01) The **framework features** set the organization:

```
- package.json
- index.android.js
- index.ios.js
- ...
- src/
    - App.js [Main file]
    - Router.js [Routes, Scenes,...]
    - actions/
        - index.js [export all]
        - types.js [constants, strings]
        - SellAction.js
        - ProductsAction.js
        - DeliveryAction.js
        - UsersAction.js
        - CartAction.js
        - ___Action.js
    - components/
        - commons/
            - Button.js
            - Card.js
            - ___.js
        - LoginForm.js
        - ProductsList.js
        - CartComponent.js
        - RecentProducts.js
        - DesirableProducts.js
        - ___.js
    - reducers/
        - index.js [combinedReducers]
        - AuthReducer.js
        - ProductsReducer.js
        - DeliveryReducer.js
        - ___Reducer.js
```

02) The **application context** set the organization:

```
- package.json
- index.android.js
- index.ios.js
- ...
- src/
    - App.js [Main file] {combinedReducers could come to here...}
    - Router.js [Routes, Scenes,...] {or here...}
    - sell/
        - Component.js
        - Action.js {the constants strings could be here...}
        - Reducer.js
        _ ... other helper files 
    - delivery/
        - Component.js
        - Action.js
        - Reducer.js
        _ ... other helper files
    - user/
        - Component.js
        - Action.js
        - Reducer.js
        _ ... other helper files
    - cart/
        - Component.js
        - Action.js
        - Reducer.js
        _ ... other helper files
```

Answer (score 0):

Either is fine.  A lot of people have expressed a preference for a "feature-first" structure.  See ([react-redux-links](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/project-structure.md)) for links to articles discussing various project structure approaches.

Comment: Thanks markerikson. It is a great reference. I love JS... but for me it is becoming a letter soup. Many names to express the same in different visions. 

I found this one https://medium.com/@yiquanzhou/how-to-structure-real-world-redux-react-application-d61e66a7dd36#.wq5dzum9j fits my conception of a project structure. Very good one,